# Can't apply RBAC command

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-rbac

When I execute the command `yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations` inside the main folder to activate the RBAC following the guide in the [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#configuring-rbac) and returns the following error "Exception 'ReflectionException' with message "Class db does not exist'in C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php:422
"

I have my db configuration correct inside of db.php file and its called in the web.php, and I can do other operations using the database. Also I added the `'authManager' => ['class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',],`
In web.php and console.php because I'm using the basic template. Don't know what's missing here.

Comment: `db` component must be also configured for console app, so make sure it's in `console.php`.

Comment: Yes its configured correctly in that file. Also added the `'authManager' => ['class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',],`

Comment: If you sure that u set up 'db' component, then your config file doesn't apply in yii.php